# How to de-serialize json in c#?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to deserialize json, I'm getting an error:

> "An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code"

My code:

```
public void w_StandingsDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
        {
            JsonSerializer jc = new JsonSerializer();
           // var o = jc.Deserialize<RootObjectStandings>(e.Result);

            var root3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectStandings>(e.Result);
            //  var root2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Headline>(e.Result);
            football f = new football();
            f.StandingList.ItemsSource = root3.info;
            f.progressbar1.IsEnabled = false;
            f.progressbar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
            f.progressbar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


        }
}
```

Class:

```
public class RootObjectStandings
{
    public int position { get; set; }
    public int team_id { get; set; }
    public string team { get; set; }
    public string teamshort { get; set; }
    public string teampath { get; set; }
    public int played { get; set; }
    public int won { get; set; }
    public int drawn { get; set; }
    public int lost { get; set; }
    public int @for { get; set; }
    public int against { get; set; }
    public int difference { get; set; }
    public Home home { get; set; }
    public Away away { get; set; }
    public int points { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}
```

and xaml code:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="StandingList" FontFamily="Arial Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-6,0,0,-26" Height="610" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Background="{x:Null}" Opacity="0.8">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Button  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Width="450" Height="Auto" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Transparent" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,5" Opacity="0.95" Foreground="White">
                                <StackPanel>

                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Left" Width="350" Height="150">
                                    <Run FontSize="23" Text="{Binding info}" />
                                    <LineBreak/>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding position}" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight"/>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

What is going wrong? help

Comment: Please post JSON, I can see invalid property name `@for` in class `RootObjectStandings`.

Comment: i generated these from jsontocsharp.com

Comment: JSON may be containing such names which are invalid in c#, so jsontocsharp will generate such wrong name. You should use `[JsonProperty]` property attribute. Please post the whole json so i can help you.

Comment: That's actually a valid property name: `@for`. The `@` allows use of reserved words. It's only invalid if the original JSON was `@for`.

Comment: This is a case where I'd suggest you consider grabbing the source for the deserializer, and using it in your solution temporarily to quickly pinpoint the error.